# Generate large set data to file, optimization resources, and code reusable

Tags: php

I must generate large set data to file.
However, i store this data in array and after i put in file.
This logical runs, but i want to respond at 2 criteria :

- optimization resources : that takes many memory during a period
- code reusable : weak coupling, separate generate data and write in file

Example :

```
class A {

public function getArrayOfData() {
    $t_header[] = [
        'col1',
        'col2',
        ...
        'colN',
    ];

    $t_body = [];

    foreach($this->objects as $object) {
        $t_oneLine = [];

        $t_oneLine[] = $object->method1($param1);
        $t_oneLine[] = $object->method2();
        ...
        $t_oneLine[] = ('toto' == $object->methodN() ? 'ok', 'failed');

        $t_body[] = $t_oneLine;
    }

    return array_merge($t_header, $t_body);
}

}


# main
$a1 = new A();
...
$o = $a1->getArrayOfData();
transformAndWriteToCsv($o);

... (i can do many processes with $o variable if i want)
```

optimization resources :

- In this example, if in getArrayOfData() method, if $objects property contain many elements, a lot memory will use at this moment to store in $t_body variable.
- weak coupling, separate generate data and write in file :

In this example, i could inject directly in file (and use php://temp with a limit to define (2MB ?) to settle this problem.
However, we obtain a tight coupling, between generation data, and use data generated.

- If i want just get data generated, i must do an other function.
- If i want to generate this data and put in different file, i must do an other function.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion, even questions to give more informations about my subject.

Comment: Are you concerned about the general use of resources or do you want to return instantly? If you have a large or complicated csv file, it would make sense to use a queue for this. Have a look at beanstalkd, redis or similiar. You would create a job and the job will be handled asynchronously. After that you can inform the user, that the download is ready.

Comment: Hello Marco,

your suggestions on asynchronous tasks are interesting.
I could use this solution.
However, my 2 criterias will be still to solve.

Comment: Do you purpose also Rabbit MQ about queue worker list ?

*

What do you think about "yield" ? 


The method "getArrayOfData()" would return "generator" and not array. 


Is it a solution whose would satisfy my 2 criterias ?

Comment: I want to avoid to crash my program causing my memory problem, and to obtain quickly result, even if i use some queue worker for some jobs.

Comment: Regarding rabbit: depends on your needs. Do you know many rows your csv file will have? It sounds like you are overcomplicating it. Regarding async or threads. I would still recommend a queue. Because you may run into the same issue sometime. Queue allows much better scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you a general answer to your question.
When processing large datasets with millions of rows, you have to tackle three main issues in php: memory usage, cpu usage and execution time. 
As you already know, loading millions of items into the ram will cause a crash of your application. Best is to use the yield operator in php. 
See snippet below:

```
function process() {
  foreach ($items as $item) {
     yield $item;
  }
}

foreach(processItem() as $item) {
 // write csv line
}
```

To tackle the ram issue, you would use a cursor to get data from db/file/etc. (so you only have one item or you could also chunk the data).

Next problem is execution time: if you have a lot of data, you script may never finish. PHP has a max. execution time so it will stop after 30 seconds (default value). Of course you can increase the limit, but this may affect the experience for other users using your website.

cpu usage: processing millions of rows will also increase the usage of cpu and also affect the experience for other users. As already mentioned, it would be good to use a queue (beanstalk, rabbitmq, etc.) You would pass a job for the export of your data and the user will be notified when its export is ready.

I hope everything is clear now.